# Unable to find typings.d.ts and declare modules in angular 2 typescript app

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I am new to Typescript and Angular 2. I need to install an npm dependency and use it in my angular 2 app.

The dependency is https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-stomp-service

I have installed the necessary packages, but I need to add the following to my `typings.d.ts` file

```
declare module 'stompjs';
declare module 'sockjs-client';
```

I am unable to find the `typings.d.ts` file in my project.

I have tried the following so far,

```
npm install typings --global
npm install @types/stompjs
npm isntall @types/sockjs-client
typings install dt~stompjs --save
typings install dt~sockjs-client --save
```

I have `typings.json` file with contents,

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "sockjs-client": "registry:dt/sockjs-client#1.0.3+20160727010356",
    "stompjs": "registry:dt/stompjs#2.3.0+20161111105645"
  }
}
```

When I run my angular 2 app with `npm start` it throws error as follows

```
ERROR in D:/Userfiles/subramanians/projects/hand-cricket/node_modules/ng2-stomp-service/dist/stomp.service.ts (27,2): Member 'config' implicitly has an 'any' type.
ERROR in D:/Userfiles/subramanians/projects/hand-cricket/node_modules/ng2-stomp-service/dist/stomp.service.ts (36,2): Member 'queuePromises' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.
ERROR in D:/Userfiles/subramanians/projects/hand-cricket/node_modules/ng2-stomp-service/dist/stomp.service.ts (83,32): Parameter 'str' implicitly has an 'any' type.
ERROR in D:/Userfiles/subramanians/projects/hand-cricket/node_modules/ng2-stomp-service/dist/stomp.service.ts (132,53): Parameter 'response' implicitly has an 'any' type.
ERROR in D:/Userfiles/subramanians/projects/hand-cricket/node_modules/ng2-stomp-service/dist/stomp.service.ts (27,2): Member 'config' implicitly has an 'any' type.
ERROR in D:/Userfiles/subramanians/projects/hand-cricket/node_modules/ng2-stomp-service/dist/stomp.service.ts (36,2): Member 'queuePromises' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.
ERROR in D:/Userfiles/subramanians/projects/hand-cricket/node_modules/ng2-stomp-service/dist/stomp.service.ts (83,32): Parameter 'str' implicitly has an 'any' type.
ERROR in D:/Userfiles/subramanians/projects/hand-cricket/node_modules/ng2-stomp-service/dist/stomp.service.ts (132,53): Parameter 'response' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

I am not sure what is causing the issue, I am guessing it is because I have not declared the modules in `typings.d.ts`

Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 17):

My two cents to this conversation:

In your tsconfig.json file make sure that you have the right path for your typings.d.ts file

> "typeRoots": [
>         "node_modules/@types",
>         "../src/typings.d.ts"
>       ],

Comment: Angular 6 doesn't add the typings.d.ts by default to your project. Older angular cli versions did.

Comment: This looked very promising, but I was forced to declare the variables in the component itself (in the ts file) instead of a separate typings.d.ts, in order to make ir work in Angular 10. Otherwise the compiler does not find the variable. Am I missing something?

Also, I think this is the main tsconfig.json, shouldn't it be src/typings.d.ts not ../ then?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your Typescript compiler tries to compile files from `node_modules` directory.

Please make sure you have this excluding rule in your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{ 
  "compilerOptions": {},
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Btw. you need just one of `@types` and `typings`. The second one is deprecated, all you need is proper `@types` packages included in your dev dependencies. Hope it helps!

EDIT: I think there shouldn't be any Typescript files in npm package, so I've created a topic with fix on this repository's github: https://github.com/devsullo/ng2-STOMP-Over-WebSocket/issues/5

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using new version of angular you can't find `typings.d.ts` file in your project. My suggestion is to update your project using angular CLI https://cli.angular.io/

Comment: Please add methods required to upgrade a project. As of July 2018 for Mac, I am not seeing this after running "ng new".