# Importing external library in angular 6 application

Tags: json, angular

In my angular app, I'm trying to import an external library `Presto.js`. I have added the below code

**angular.json**

```
"scripts": [
    "./src/assets/presto/Presto.js"
]
```

**example.component.ts**

```
import  * as Presto  from '../../assets/presto/Presto';

ngOnInit() { 
    debugger;
    Presto.layout();
}
```

When it hits the debugger, I can see the method `layout()` in it, but when the debug point it released, the below error is thrown

```
TypeError: _assets_presto_Presto__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__["layout"] is not a function.
```

Does anyone have any idea on this..

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44817445/3634032)

Comment: You may find it in your `window` object, try with debugger

Comment: @SamHerrmann I already tried this except typings.d.ts, which I can't find in angular 6 app

Comment: @TusharWalzade I can find it even with out the window object when I put debug point..but still getting error

Comment: You could try [this](https://gist.github.com/jeffwhelpley/2d14a615790af18b3549#gistcomment-2111412)

Comment: Yeah the CLI used to included typings.d.ts by default, but it no longer does. You can add it yourself though and tell the compiler about it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48727744/3634032).

Comment: @I'm nidhin did you figure it out? Coincidently I need to add a global library today to a new project and I'm struggling to get the custom typings to work too. This used to be no issue. I'm, using Angular + CLI 7.3.0 and followed the [instructions in the docs](https://angular.io/guide/using-libraries#defining-typings-for-runtime-global-libraries)